# No permission to automount external HDD using ntfs-3g

Tags: mount, permissions, ntfs, external-hdd, ntfs-3g

I wanted to modify my mount options for my NTFS external HDD so that I can execute programs on it.  I added the following line to my fstab accordingly:

```
UUID=CE665A3F665A290B  /media/Josh  ntfs-3g defaults,users,nofail 0 0
```

But when I plug in my external and I get this error:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
Error opening '/dev/sdb1': Permission denied
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Permission denied
Please check '/dev/sdb1' and the ntfs-3g binary permissions, and the mounting user ID. More explanation is provided at http://tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged.
```

Soo I go to the URL provided.  It says:

> Unprivileged block device mounts work only if all the below requirements are met:
>
> 1. ntfs-3g is compiled with integrated FUSE support
> 2. the ntfs-3g binary is at least version 1.2506
> 3. the ntfs-3g binary is set to setuid-root
> 4. the user has access right to the volume
> 5. the user has access right to the mount point

I believe I have all 5 requirements met (though obviously not, since I'm getting that error).  Anyone have some tips?  In particular, I have:

> 1. ntfs-3g 2014.2.15 integrated FUSE 27
> 2. ntfs-3g 2014.2.15 integrated FUSE 27
> 3. -rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 504887 Mar  8 12:06 /bin/ntfs-3g*
> 4. brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 Mar  8 16:43 /dev/sdb1  (my user is in the "disk" group)
> 5. drwxrwxrwx  2 josh josh 4096 Mar  8 12:42 Josh/

Been struggling with this for hours.  This [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1661757) has been the most helpful so far, but notably the last post has my same question and is unanswered.

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you see that error? In `dmesg`? Are you running any `mount` commands or is this happening automatically when you pluf the drive in?

Comment: I get a pop-up with that error.  This happens automatically when I plug the drive in, I'm not running any commands at all :(

Comment: The message is shown when you plug it, but who throws the message? GNOME? Nautilus? Unity? Does `/media/Josh` exist? What are the permissions? Add the output of just running `ntfs-3g` in the terminal.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you change `ntfs-36` to `ntfs` in the `fstab`? I don't think that would give that error but it's worth a shot. Also, please show the output of `ls -ld /media /media/Josh` to make sure that both directories have the right permissions.

Comment: I got the same error.  ls -ld /media/Josh: (drwxrwxrwx 2 josh josh 4096 Mar 8 12:42 Josh/)    ls -ld /media: (drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar  8 18:19 /media)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer that lets me not edit my fstab to get what I want.  Since my disk gets automounted, I added a rule to my udev that told the automount to do something special upon plug-in (that I don't really understand).  But now my disk gets automounted with all files executable.  I created a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-disks.rules` and added:

```
ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="ntfs", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}="ntfs-3g"
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1914416&p=11636662#post11636662

Still haven't found a way to get rid of my permissions error when I do use my fstab mod, though.

Thanks terdon for the help.